# Is there a limit on unit number (other than being a positive integer) in gfortran Open statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a limit on the unit number ( the one specified as unit= ) in Open statement in GFortran.
I realize it needs to be a positive integer.
In early fortran manuals I believe it was a small positive integer under 100.
I used numbers beyond that but under 300 in GFortran and now wondering if I can use numbers as large a 1000,  even 10000.
I could not find any mention of a limit in GFortran manual.

Comment: To avoid this problem all together consider using the `newunit` specifier on the open statement - available in gfortran since version 7.3   (Jan 2018). See for example https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/file-operation-i-o-statements/open-statement-specifiers/open-newunit-specifier.html#open-newunit-specifier

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the typical 32-bit `integer` values apply, but only the non-negative values.

That would be `0` to `2,147,483,647` (which is evaluated from `2**31-1`)

Interestingly the documentation for [`Intel Fortran`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-transfer-i-o-statements/components-of-data-transfer-statements/i-o-control-list/unit-specifier-unit.html#unit-specifier-unit) states the domain is `0` to `2,147,483,643` which means to me the compiler has reserved some values for special purposes.

I assume `gfortran` might do the same, so the true max value is undetermined right now, although I bet it is a lot higher than `10000`.

Comment: The Intel documentation is wrong on the limit - a unit number of 2,147,483,647 works fine - I will report that to the writers. Of the positive integers, units 0, 5 and 6 are "preconnected". Negative numbers -1 through -5 ARE reserved, which is why NEWUNIT numbers start below those.

Comment: Can confirm that GFortran uses a 32-bit signed integer for the unit number.